# Conversion Failed Converting VARCHAR to INT

Tags: sql-server

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1
>   12:57:39  3168.68 485 H5555' to data type int. This occurred in SQL
>   Server 2012 for the following code.

```
SELECT 
MEMBER_ID
,STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',[' + C1 + '-' + C2 + ']' AS [text()]
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT A.MEMBER_ID
            ,A.CLAIM_ID AS C1
            ,A.PLAN_ID AS PC1
            ,B.CLAIM_ID C2
            ,B.PLAN_ID AS PC2
            ,A.AMOUNT AS AMT1
            ,B.AMOUNT AS AMT2
            FROM TestSQL A 
            JOIN TestSQL B ON A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID 
            WHERE A.CLAIM_ID <> '1 12:57:39 3168.68 485 H5555' 
            AND YEAR(A.DATE) > 2000 
            AND B.DATE > A.DATE 
            AND B.PLAN_ID <> A.PLAN_ID 
            AND (CAST(B.CLAIM_ID AS INT)-CAST(A.CLAIM_ID AS INT))=2
        ) Y             
        WHERE MEMBER_ID = X.MEMBER_ID
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
) AS CLAIM_ID_LIST
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.MEMBER_ID
    ,A.CLAIM_ID AS C1
    ,A.PLAN_ID AS PC1
    ,B.CLAIM_ID C2
    ,B.PLAN_ID AS PC2
    ,A.AMOUNT AS AMT1
    ,B.AMOUNT AS AMT2
    FROM TestSQL A 
    JOIN TestSQL B ON A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID
    WHERE YEAR(A.DATE) > 2000  
    AND B.DATE > A.DATE 
    AND B.PLAN_ID <> A.PLAN_ID 
    AND (CAST(B.CLAIM_ID AS INT)-CAST(A.CLAIM_ID AS INT))=2 
    AND A.CLAIM_ID IN (SELECT CLAIM_ID FROM TestSQL WHERE MEMBER_ID<>'')
) X
```

I have tried to filter out `1 12:57:39  3168.68 485 H5555` and still gives me this error. This is a `CLAIM_ID`. I suspect it's the

```
WHERE MEMBER_ID = X.MEMBER_ID
```

clause right above the FOR XML PATH but I don't know why. The second subquery works. I appreciate any insights on this.

Comment: What's the data type of your `CLAIM_ID`?

Comment: VARCHAR. But I did a CAST to INT. The second subquery, right above the X, includes that and that subquery works.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You have a '1 12:57:39 3168.68 485 H5555' in your `CLAIM_ID`, you might want to filter that first in a subquery.

Comment: You're casting CLAIM_ID to int for both A and B in the subquery aliased `X`, without saying to ignore '1 12:57:39 3168.68 485 H5555'

Comment: I did filter that out (as I mentioned) and it still grumbles about this.

Answer (score 3):

This is where the error came from:

```
(CAST(B.CLAIM_ID AS INT)-CAST(A.CLAIM_ID AS INT)) = 2
```

Casting `1 12:57:39 3168.68 485 H5555` to `INT` will produce an error. Though you said you've filtered it out in `WHERE A.CLAIM_ID <> '1 12:57:39 3168.68 485 H5555'`. The optimizer may opt to evaluate the `CAST` first and thus result an error.

You may want to filter that out first in a `CTE`. Then use that `CTE` instead:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM TestSQL
    WHERE
        CLAIM_ID <> '1 12:57:39 3168.68 485 H5555'
)
SELECT 
MEMBER_ID
,STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',[' + C1 + '-' + C2 + ']' AS [text()]
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT A.MEMBER_ID
            ,A.CLAIM_ID AS C1
            ,A.PLAN_ID AS PC1
            ,B.CLAIM_ID C2
            ,B.PLAN_ID AS PC2
            ,A.AMOUNT AS AMT1
            ,B.AMOUNT AS AMT2
            FROM CTE A 
            JOIN CTE B ON A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID 
            WHERE A.CLAIM_ID <> '1 12:57:39 3168.68 485 H5555' 
            AND YEAR(A.DATE) > 2000 
            AND B.DATE > A.DATE 
            AND B.PLAN_ID <> A.PLAN_ID 
            AND (CAST(B.CLAIM_ID AS INT)-CAST(A.CLAIM_ID AS INT))=2
        ) Y             
        WHERE MEMBER_ID = X.MEMBER_ID
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
) AS CLAIM_ID_LIST
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.MEMBER_ID
    ,A.CLAIM_ID AS C1
    ,A.PLAN_ID AS PC1
    ,B.CLAIM_ID C2
    ,B.PLAN_ID AS PC2
    ,A.AMOUNT AS AMT1
    ,B.AMOUNT AS AMT2
    FROM CTE A 
    JOIN CTE B ON A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID
    WHERE YEAR(A.DATE) > 2000  
    AND B.DATE > A.DATE 
    AND B.PLAN_ID <> A.PLAN_ID 
    AND (CAST(B.CLAIM_ID AS INT)-CAST(A.CLAIM_ID AS INT))=2 
    AND A.CLAIM_ID IN (SELECT CLAIM_ID FROM CTE WHERE MEMBER_ID<>'')
) X
```

---

To make sure only numeric `CLAIM_ID` will be returned, you may use this inside the `CTE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TestSQL
WHERE CLAIM_ID NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: There's no way to filter it out without using CTE?

Comment: Use a subquery. Remember you must filter it out first, not together with the `CAST`. The optimizer may evaluate the `CAST` first.

Comment: You could also insert them in a temp table or table variable first.

Comment: How can I use a subquery to filter it out?

Comment: Replace all `FROM TestSQL`, `JOIN TestSQL` with the subquery. Why can't you use CTE?

Comment: @Dombey; a CTE is basically the same thing as a subquery; only instead of repeating the same subquery several times (and therefore SQL having to run the same code several times) you do it once, then reuse the results of that subquery everywhere it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
--use cte to create a copy of the table minus the dodgy row
--or simply set that claim to null and cast remaining values
--use this anywhere we need to cast claim_id to int
;with cte as 
(
    select *
    , case 
        when CLAIM_ID = '1 12:57:39 3168.68 485 H5555' 
            then null 
        else 
            cast(CLAIM_ID as int) 
    end CLAIM_ID_INT
    from TestSQL
)
SELECT 
MEMBER_ID
,STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',[' + C1 + '-' + C2 + ']' AS [text()]
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT A.MEMBER_ID
            ,A.CLAIM_ID AS C1
            ,A.PLAN_ID AS PC1
            ,B.CLAIM_ID C2
            ,B.PLAN_ID AS PC2
            ,A.AMOUNT AS AMT1
            ,B.AMOUNT AS AMT2
            FROM cte A 
            JOIN cte B ON A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID 
            WHERE A.CLAIM_ID <> '1 12:57:39 3168.68 485 H5555' 
            AND YEAR(A.DATE) > 2000 
            AND B.DATE > A.DATE 
            AND B.PLAN_ID <> A.PLAN_ID 
            AND (B.CLAIM_ID_INT - A.CLAIM_ID_INT)=2
        ) Y             
        WHERE Y.MEMBER_ID = X.MEMBER_ID
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
) AS CLAIM_ID_LIST
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.MEMBER_ID
    ,A.CLAIM_ID AS C1
    ,A.PLAN_ID AS PC1
    ,B.CLAIM_ID C2
    ,B.PLAN_ID AS PC2
    ,A.AMOUNT AS AMT1
    ,B.AMOUNT AS AMT2
    FROM cte A 
    JOIN cte B ON A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID
    WHERE YEAR(A.DATE) > 2000  
    AND B.DATE > A.DATE 
    AND B.PLAN_ID <> A.PLAN_ID 
    AND B.CLAIM_ID_INT-A.CLAIM_ID_INT = 2 
    AND A.CLAIM_ID IN (SELECT CLAIM_ID FROM cte WHERE MEMBER_ID<>'')
) X
```